# LightGBM package not installing on a windows machine

Tags: r, lightgbm

I am trying to install LightGBM on my windows laptop. I have it installed on an AWS Ubuntu/Lunix instance but I keep getting errors on my windows laptop...

In the terminal using my RStudio windows version I run:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM
cd LightGBM
Rscript build_r.R
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.17763.1039]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.   # Spanish but all rights reserved.

C:\Users\USER\Documents>git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM
Cloning into 'LightGBM'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 207, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (207/207), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (172/172), done.

Receiving objects: 100% (16659/16659), 11.36 MiB | 1.86 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12071/12071), done.
Submodule 'include/boost/compute' (https://github.com/boostorg/compute) registered for path 'compu
te'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/USER/Documents/LightGBM/compute'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 21728, done.
remote: Total 21728 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 21728
Receiving objects: 100% (21728/21728), 8.51 MiB | 1.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (17565/17565), done.
Submodule path 'compute': checked out '36c89134d4013b2e5e45bc55656a18bd6141995a'

C:\Users\USER\Documents>cd LightGBM

C:\Users\USER\Documents\LightGBM>Rscript build_r.R
* checking for file 'lightgbm_r/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'lightgbm':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
Warning in cleanup_pkg(pkgdir, Log) :
  unable to run 'make clean' in 'src'
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
* building 'lightgbm_2.3.2.tar.gz'

* installing to library 'C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
* installing *source* package 'lightgbm' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'lightgbm'
* removing 'C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/lightgbm'
Error in .run_shell_command(cmd) : Command failed with exit code: 1
Ejecución interrumpida
```

Error: `Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found`
I have tried many times to install `make` . I have updated Rtools also.

Edit 1:

Session Info:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2        rstudioapi_0.10   magrittr_1.5      usethis_1.5.1     devtools_2.1.0   
 [6] pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.4.0          rlang_0.4.0       tools_3.6.1       pkgbuild_1.0.4   
[11] sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_1.1.0         withr_2.1.2       remotes_2.1.0     assertthat_0.2.1 
[16] digest_0.6.21     rprojroot_1.3-2   crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.4.1    callr_3.3.1      
[21] fs_1.3.1          ps_1.3.0          curl_4.0          testthat_2.2.1    memoise_1.1.0    
[26] glue_1.3.1        compiler_3.6.1    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.4   prettyunits_1.0.2
```

EDIT 2:

```
I managed to pass the `make not found` argument, when I run the code now I get.


$ Rscript build_r.R
* checking for file 'lightgbm_r/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'lightgbm':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
* building 'lightgbm_2.3.2.tar.gz'

* installing to library 'C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
* installing *source* package 'lightgbm' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
installing via 'install.libs.R' to C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-lightgbm/00new
/lightgbm
Warning in system(paste0(tmp_cmake_cmd, " ..")) : 'cmake' not found
Warning in system(paste0(tmp_cmake_cmd, " ..")) : 'cmake' not found
Warning in system(paste0(tmp_cmake_cmd, " ..")) : 'cmake' not found
Warning in system(paste0(cmake_cmd, " ..")) : 'cmake' not found
Warning in system(build_cmd) : 'cmake' not found
Error in eval(ei, envir) : Cannot find lib_lightgbm.dll
* removing 'C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/lightgbm'
Error in .run_shell_command(cmd) : Command failed with exit code: 1
Ejecución interrumpida
```

I downloaded `cmake` but I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to install `Rtools`, see [https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). Note that `rtools` is *not* a package that can be installed with `install.packages("rtools")`.

Comment: I downloaded this and updated it to the `beta` version. My only guess is that my current R version is not finding it.

Comment: You are missing `Rtools` which provides `make`. Follow the instructions from the link I give in my first comment, then try re-installing with `install.packages("lightgbm")`. BTW, from the [`LightGBM` GH site](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/R-package), the first thing under Windows preparation is "**Installing Rtools is mandatory**, and only support the 64-bit version. It requires to add to PATH the Rtools MinGW64 folder, if it was not done automatically during installation." (bold-face mine).

Comment: I have Rtools installed. When I run `install.packages("lightgbm")` I get `Warning in install.packages : package lightgbm is not available (for R version 3.6.1)` when I try with `devtools` using `devtools::install_github("Laurae2/lgbdl")` I get `Skipping install of 'lgbdl' from a github remote, the SHA1 (b3691920) has not changed since last install. Use force = TRUE to force installation`. I added my `sessionInfo()` to the original post.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood your earlier comment then. Are you sure the folder that contains the `make` binary is in your `PATH`?

Comment: That could very well be the issue, I am not sure how to exactly find how to do this part.

Comment: What does `Sys.getenv("PATH")` return?

Comment: `> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.1\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208219/discussion-between-maurits-evers-and-user113156).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments from chat, it seems you've installed `Rtools` into a non-standard folder (something other than `C:/Rtools`), which may have resulted in `C:/Rtools/bin` not being part of your `PATH`.

Try the following

```r
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/Rtools/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
```

Make sure you change `"C:/Rtools/bin"` to reflect the folder in which you installed `Rtools`.

If the folder is `C:\rtools40`, change it do

```r
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/rtools40/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
```

Then try re-installing `lightgbm` as per the official instructions.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and tried re-installing again but I get the same error `make not found`. I look in the folder `C:\RBuildTools\3.5\bin` and see that there is a file called `make`.So I add this to the `Sys.setend` path and re-install but get the same error. In the file path `C:/rtools40/` there is no `bin` folder. However in `C:\rtools40\mingw64` I do have a `bin` folder which does not contain a `make` file. A search for `make` on my computer gives the following file locations `C:/rtools40/var/lib/pacman/local/make-4.2.1-9400`.

Comment: `C:/rtools40/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/locale/Maketext`, `C:/rtools40/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/MakeMaker`, `C:/rtools40/usr/share/makepkg-template`, `c:rtools40/usr/share/makepkg`.

Comment: @user113156 That's very strange. To clarify so we're on the same page: (1) You installed `Rtools` into folder `C:/RBuildTools`? And (2) There is a folder `C:/RBuildTools/3.5/bin` that contains `make`? Then where does `C:/rtools40` come from? Did you install `Rtools` multiple times? I suggest taking a step back and starting fresh: Remove all `Rtools` installations. Then install `Rtools` (preferably into the default directory). Then double-check that the `bin` folder of your `Rtools` installation is in your path (should be automatic).

Comment: Yes! but I used a bunch of different methods and solutions. From downloading visual studio to a whole host of different methods, that I cannot say which particular method solved my issue. I did manage to install it in the end though. If I recall correctly my windows machine was missing some packages / files.

Comment: Rtools for me was also installed to `C:\rtools40` but I found make in `C:\rtools40\usr\bin`.